# How to transfer AWS Route 53 domain name to home BIND server

Tags: 16.04, aws, bind

I've been playing around with the idea of hosting my own websites. I've launched a multitude of Ubuntu Servers each with different configurations. My last one was with Plesk installed on it. Pretty neat application.

I have a domain name that is currently residing on Route 53 and I have a public IP from my ISP. I have both port 80 and 443 forwarded to my static internal IP. My website is always accessible from the internet but only using my external IP address.

How do I point the DNS servers to my own if I install BIND on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? I already tried pointing my Route 53 IP address to my external IP but that didn't work. There is also a Transfer Lock on the registered domains page. Do I unlock it?

Answer (score 0):

Pointing your domain name to home IP should totally work in your scenario.

See if you can troubleshoot it, you need to only update A records and possibly www CNAME to use that public IP from your ISP.

If you absolutely must move from Route 53, you still won't be able to do properly using a single IP you have at home: usually, DNS zone needs at least two NS servers with different IP addresses (more information here: https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements)